# Same width in different columns using css

Tags: css, column-width

I have to columns, lets say rside and lside. They dont have fixed height. I want each time to adjust their width accordingly. So if lside is bigger, rside should be the same height.

So both of them should have some height according to the higher of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it by javascript - get size of both and than set the bigger one to smaller column :-) I think you cant do it by css if you dont know size of content before.

Comment: Its like "document.getElementById("id").clientHeight" or 

"document.getElementById("id").offsetHeight" and than set it like "document.getElementById("id").height = ..."

Comment: The other answer looks pretty cool, but i dont think it will work if there is something else between your two divs... or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks , the best explanation of achieving equal height columns and I'm sure a lot of people have asked this question.

Other answers on StackOverflow:- 
1) [HTML/CSS: Making two floating divs the same height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205159/html-css-making-two-floating-divs-the-same-height/) 
2) [Columns of Equal Height with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354493/columns-of-equal-height-with-jquery)

Comment: i searched in stackoverflow but i didnt find anything interesting

Comment: did you check the above questions which answer the same ? if it helps you please don't forget to select the answer :) !